# Implement clone defined in an Interface returning the concrete class?

Tags: java, oop, clone

I am reading DesignPatterns ('GoF patterns') and implementing the Example `MazeGame`. While reading about Prototypes, I ran into a thing writing the  clone method (`cloneIt()`).

First of all my structure:

Interface: `MapSite`

AbstractClass: `AbstractMapSite`

Concrete Impl: `Room`, `Door`, `Wall`

My plan is to define `cloneIt` in `MapSite` and give a default implementation (simply calling `Object.clone()`), which can be overidden in the concrete classes. Now the `cloneIt()` method always returns the interface type `MapSite`.

*Is there a way to 'force' Java to return the concrete class type (`Room, Door, Wall`) eventhough the method from the abstract class is used?* This may avoid castings.

I know about the pros of Interfaces and why they are used :)

**Solution**

As @philipp-wendler and @davidxxx suggested, I ended up using generics. In case the shallow copy of `Object.clone()` is a problem, I override `cloneIt()` in the concrete class.

```
public interface MapSite<T> extends Serializable {
    T cloneIt();
}
...

public abstract class AbstractMapSite<T> implements MapSite<T> {
    public T cloneIt() {
        try {
            return (T) clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
...

public class Wall extends AbstractMapSite<Wall> {
    public Wall cloneIt(){
        // special code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you wanna do that, what are the benefits

Comment: @blackHawk I call `clone()` for copying a prototype of my objects (`Door, Wall, Room`) and do not want to cast them. In this case, I have no use of treating all objects as `MapSite` implmentations. So I wondered if there's a smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My plan is to define cloneIt in MapSite and give a default
>   implementation (simply calling Object.clone()), which can be overidden
>   in the concrete classes.

Be aware : the default implementation of `Object.clone()` makes a shallow copy of the cloned object and you should also implement the `Cloneable` interface if you don't want to see a `CloneNotSupportedException` be thrown.

So you should override both `clone()` and `cloneIt()`. It is confusing because a single method is enough. Just keep `cloneIt()` and forget the clumsy `clone()` method.

> Is there a way to 'force' Java to return the concrete class type
>   (Room, Door, Wall) eventhough the method from the abstract class is
>   used? This may avoid castings.

With Generics yes you can do it.

For example :

```
public interface MapSite<T>{
  T cloneIt();
}

public abstract class AbstractMapSite<T> implements MapSite<T>{
  ...
}


public class Wall extends AbstractMapSite<Wall>{
   public Wall cloneIt(){
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know `clone` is shallow, but I have objects without other object members so this is fine for some classes. That is why I introduced `cloneIt`.

Comment: You are welcome :) I see but `clone()` has multiple defaults  (it throws checked exception that you have to handle it, it is not a specific enough contract, it is not a real interface to implement, ...). Not implementing `clone()` and providing a single method to clone (`cloneIt()` here) could make things more clear for the client classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive generic type:

```
public interface MapSite<T extends MapSite<T>> { 

  T cloneIt();
}

public abstract class AbstractMapSite<T extends AbstractMapSite<T>> implements MapSite<T> {
}

public class Room extends AbstractMapSite<Room> {
  public Room cloneIt() { ... }
}
```

This type forces non-abstract subclasses of `MapSite` to declare `T` as their own type, thus guaranteeing the correct return type of `cloneIt`.

You could also implement `cloneIt` in the abstract class if you call `clone()` and use an unchecked cast to `T`.

Comment: Thanks! I need the recursion to make sure the cloned type implements MapSite, right?

Comment: You need the recursion to make sure that the cloned type is exactly the type of the concrete class. Otherwise `Room` could for example `implement MapSite<Wall>` and return `Wall`s from `cloneIt`.

Comment: From your example `Room extends MapSite<Wall>` is still possible, with `cloneIt` returning Wall instead of Room. But that's wrong usage anyhow.